# How to limit the range of interdependent sliders?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, slider

Two sliders are used to display the values of an interval.
The range is for example 0 - 100, which is set in the sliders' min and max properties.
I want to make sure, that the sliders values can not pass each other. The thumb of the slider for the lower value of the interval must not be dragged past the value of the second slider and vice versa.

Binding the value of the first slider to one of the min/max Properties of the other slider (and vice versa) results in the second slider's thumb to be moved while the first one is modified, since the range is changing. So I want to keep the range of both sliders fixed.

How could I limit the thumb movement?

Thanks!

Update:

In my attached property I subscribe to ValueChanged event which is handled in OnSliderMoved:

```
private static void OnSliderMoved(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> args)
{
  double min = GetMin((DependencyObject)sender);
  double max = GetMax((DependencyObject)sender);

  if (sender is Slider)
  {
    var sld = (Slider)sender;

    var currentValue = sld.Value;
    //check if the value has changed at all
    if (Math.Abs(args.NewValue - args.OldValue) < 0)
    {
      args.Handled = true;
      return;
    }

    double val = 0.0;

    var result = ValidationResult.Ok;

    try
    {
        try
        {
          val = Convert.ToDouble(currentValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
          val = Math.Round(val + 0.0005, 3);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {              
          throw;
        }

        result = ExceedsLimits(val, (double)minimum, (double)maximum);
      }          
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
      result = ValidationResult.TooLarge;
    }


    switch (result)
    {
      case ValidationResult.TooLarge:
        // reset the slider value to maximum
        sld.Value = max;
        args.Handled = true;
        break;
      case ValidationResult.TooSmall:
        // reset the slider value to minimum
        sld.Value = min;
        args.Handled = true;
        break;
      case ValidationResult.Ok:
        BindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(sld, RangeBase.ValueProperty);

        if (binding != null)
        {
          binding.UpdateSource();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}


<Slider x:Name="sldMaxPercent"
        Value="{Binding SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, 
        Converter={optimat:DoulbeToPercentForSliderConverter}}"
        Maximum="100"                                                
        Minimum="0" 
        input:InputService.Min="{Binding ElementName=sldMinPercent, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        input:InputService.Max="100"
        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
        IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        TickFrequency="0.1">
```

With this, the thumb movement gets stopped, which is what I wanted.
The problem is, that if I continue to drag the mouse in the blocked direction the binding gets updated although the thumb is not moving in that direction.

How can I interrupt the binding updates?

Comment: When moving your slider, you can check whether it can be moved further or not. Just use ValueChanged event.

Comment: You might want to use a range slider control, like e.g. this one: http://mahapps.com/controls/range-slider.html

Comment: @MacakM: thanks, that was what I was looking for. I ended up creating an attached property that used OnValueChanged to check if the Value is in the desired range.

Comment: @Clemens: I guess that would be a better solution, but in my application the sliders need to stay separated

Answer (score 1):

The use of a simple view model like this should result in the expected behaviour:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double lowerValue;
    public double LowerValue
    {
        get { return lowerValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= upperValue)
            {
                lowerValue = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LowerValue"));
            }
        }
    }

    private double upperValue;
    public double UpperValue
    {
        get { return upperValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= lowerValue)
            {
                upperValue = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UpperValue"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bind two Sliders to the two properties of the view model:

```
<Slider Maximum="100" Value="{Binding LowerValue}"/>
<Slider Maximum="100" Value="{Binding UpperValue}"/>
```

Comment: Problem is, that the Min and Max Property are located in a generic class where I can't do a value comparison between values of type T. My ViewModel only provides a list of those objects.